# LARAVEL : what's the best practice for devide a template like a senior programmer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I created a template using html/css/jquery
this template contains

show All Posts

show one post

show dashboard for admin

```
/
/posts
/posts/1
/admin
/admin/dashboard
/admin/config
/admin/createpost
/admin/editpost
/admin/showpost
/admin/showAllPosts
/admin/createCategorie
```

etc ...............

I want to know how what's the easiest way and best practice  for divide my template in `views Folder`
and wich structure should I follow
I want be like a laravel senior programmers

Comment: https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices take a look this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is: It depends on your project structure.

These are at least two things I have learned throughout years of laravel development:

- Splitting your views in too many files is a really bad practice and make support very complex
- Code repetition among views is a really bad practice too

So here are some tips:

- You should identify what parts of your projects are going to be present in multiple pages/views, and make a separate view for them.
- If a view is present in one and only one specific page or parent view, don't create a separate file for it.
- If a view is present in all pages, it should be in the layout view.
- All pages should `extend` a layout view. If you have multiple type of pages (ex: pages in the administration panel, and pages in the public website), you can have multiple layouts. One layout per page group.
- After developing all of this, you should search and identify the code that is repeated in multiple pages, and create a view for each of them. I said that because while developing, we copy/paste sometimes, just to test something and we forget to clean it up afterwards.